# In how many ways can $5$ rings of different types be worn on $4$ fingers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can $5$ rings of different types be worn on $4$ fingers?

According to me,first finger have $5$ ways,second finger have $4$ ways,
third finger have $3$ ways and last finger have $2$ ways.

Therefore there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 120$ arrangements.

***But in my textbook it's answer is $4^5$.***

Comment: That is a bit strange: the answer of your book does not consider the order of the rings on each finger.

Comment: please answer this question math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910579/… since I am new on this site I don't know how to attract users towards my question.Please tell me how to gain attention of other users.And please answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textbook goes for: "each of the $5$ rings has a choice out of $4$ fingers."

Comment: @RafaelNadal Then practicize the rule: no information=no limitation. But I admit that the question is not very well stated. You could also wonder: does the order of the rings on the fingers play a part? If e.g. all rings are on the same fingers then still there are $5!$ arrangements.

Comment: I do not like the answer in the textbook since at least two rings must be placed on the same finger and the order in which distinct rings are placed on a finger matters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I fully agree with that.

Comment: thanks I got it I think @rafael  is answer

Comment: please answer this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910579/how-to-identify-whether-permutation-question-involves-repetition-or-not   since I am new on this site I don't know how to attract users towards my question.Please tell me how to gain attention of other users.And please answer this question

Comment: @J.Doe I know only one way to attract attention: a bonus. But you have no reputation enough for that (yet), I guess.

Comment: @drhab what is bonus?anyways I got your attention so please answer my question sier

Answer (score 2):

This question is not well stated. This question doesn't shows information about the limitation of number of ring on a particular finger.
According to you it's limitation is 1 but in your book it doesn't have limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order of rings on each finger is not important, you can look at the problem in the following way: take the first ring, you have 4 options (fingers) for it, right? Next ring, you have the same number of options, so it is $4 \times 4 = 4^2$, and so on. For 5 rings it is obviously $4^5$.